# Density of a set of natural numbers which are the product of close numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$.  A natural number $x$ is called an $\varepsilon$-square if $x = ab$, $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(1 - \varepsilon)b \le a \le b$.  Denote by $f(N)$ the number of $\varepsilon$-squares on the interval $[1, N]$.  Is it true that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{f(N)}{N} = 0$?

There is at least $cN$, for some constant $c > 0$, pairs of natural numbers $(a, b)$ such that $(1 - \varepsilon)b \le a \le b$ and $ab \le N$.  But the product of such pairs can define the same $\varepsilon$-squares.  For example, we can take $x = \prod_{i = 1}^{2m}p_i$, where $p_i$ are prime numbers close enough to each other.  Then there are $\binom{2m}{m}$ representations $x = ab$.

Comment: I believe it is known that most natural numbers have a large prime factor. Such numbers will fail to be $\varepsilon$-squares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x\leq N$ is an $\varepsilon$-square, then $x=ab$ and $a\leq b\leq \sqrt{x/(1-\varepsilon)}=:K$. So, $x$ should appear in $K\times K$ multiplication table. It is known, however, that most numbers below $K^2$ are not in this multiplication table, see [Erdős–Tenenbaum–Ford constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tenenbaum%E2%80%93Ford_constant). If $M(K)$ is the number of distinct elements in multiplication table $K\times K$, then for $K\to +\infty$ we have
$$
M(K)=\frac{K^2}{(\ln K)^{\delta+o(1)}},
$$
where $\delta\approx 0.086$. In particular, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there are $o(K^2)=o(N)$ numbers below $N$, which are $\varepsilon$-squares.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should have $$f_\epsilon(N) \asymp_\epsilon \frac{N}{(\log N)^{\delta_0}(\log\log N)^{3/2}},$$ where $X \asymp_\epsilon Y$ means $X \le C_\epsilon Y$ and $X \ge c_\epsilon Y$ for some constants $C_\epsilon,c_\epsilon > 0$, and $$\delta_0 := 1-\frac{1+\log\log 2}{\log 2}.$$

What follows is a proof of the upper bound and a near-proof of the lower bound. The lower bound might follow from a close analysis of work of Ford.

For the upper bound, note that if $n \le N$ is of the form $n = ab$ with $(1-\epsilon)b \le a \le b$, then $a,b \le (1-\epsilon)^{-1/2}N^{1/2}$. Therefore, $$f_\epsilon(N) \le \Big|\big[(1-\epsilon)^{-1/2}N^{1/2}\big]\cdot\big[(1-\epsilon)^{-1/2}N^{1/2}\big]\Big|,$$ where $[m] := \{1,\dots,m\}$ and $A\cdot B := \{ab : a \in A, b \in B\}$. Ford [proved](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401223) that $$\Big|\big[M\big]\cdot\big[M\big]\Big| \asymp \frac{M^2}{(\log M)^{\delta_0}(\log\log M)^{3/2}},$$ which indeed gives the upper bound.

As for the lower bound, note that \begin{align*}f_\epsilon(N) &\ge \Bigg|\bigg\{n \in \Big[\big(1-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\big)N,N\Big] : \exists d \mid n \text{ s.t. } d \in \Big[(1-\epsilon)^{1/2}N^{1/2},(1-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)^{1/2}N^{1/2}\Big]\bigg\}\Bigg| \\ &= H\Big(N,(1-\epsilon)^{1/2}N^{1/2},(1-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)^{1/2}N^{1/2}\Big) - H\Big((1-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)N,(1-\epsilon)^{1/2}N^{1/2},(1-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)^{1/2}N^{1/2}\Big),\end{align*} where, as in Ford's notation, $H(x,y,z)$ denotes the number of $n \le x$ with a divisor in the interval $[y,z]$. So the question is whether Ford can handle small-ish intervals $[(1-\delta)x,x]$ rather than just the full interval $[1,x]$.